# Receiving XML error when Validating with xmllint

Tags: xml, dtd, xml-validation

When I use xmllint to check my DTD file I get an error message. Please see the output below. I'm not exactly sure where this has all gone wrong.

```
book.dtd:1: parser error : StartTag: invalid element name
<!ELEMENT books_for_sale (book+)>
 ^
book.dtd:1: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document
<!ELEMENT books_for_sale (book+)>
 ^
```

Here is my DTD file

```
<!ELEMENT books_for_sale (book+)>
<!ELEMENT book (book_id, title, author, co_author_name, editor_name, illustrator_name, language, ISBN, publisher, publisher_date, genre, subject, category, file_size, pages, price, payment_method)>
<!ELEMENT book_id (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT author (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT co_author_name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT editor_name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT illustrator_name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT language (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT ISBN (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT publisher (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT publisher_date (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT genre (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT subject (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT category (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT file_size (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT pages (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT price (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT payment_method (#PCDATA)>
```

Not sure if the combination of html and xml is done properly. Tried using Namespaces to keep this sorted out. But this is all new to me so I'm not sure if it's written correctly.

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="utf-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE books_for_sale SYSTEM "book.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:BO="http://resumator3000.com">

<!-- list book inventory -->

<head>
<title>Book Order</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="book.css"></link>
</head>
<body>

<div class="page-wrap">

<h3>Books for Sale</h3>
<h4>Great Prices! Limted Selection! No Delivery!</h4>

<!-- present books for sale -->
<BO:books_for_sale>

    <BO:book>
        <p>Book ID: <BO:book_id>BK12345</BO:book_id></p>
        <p>Book Title: <BO:title>Gray Geese Crying</BO:title></p>
        <p>Author: <BO:author>Bill Nedham</BO:author></p>
        <p>Co-Author: <BO:co_author_name>Surely Joking</BO:co_author_name></p>
        <p>Editor: <BO:editor_name>Fried Brian</BO:editor_name></p>
        <p>Illustrator: <BO:illustrator_name>Drew Sumthin</BO:illustrator_name></p>
        <p>Language: <BO:language>Orangatang</BO:language></p>
        <p>ISBN: <BO:ISBN>9912385748391</BO:ISBN></p>
        <p>Publisher: <BO:publisher>Random Random Homes</BO:publisher></p>
        <p>Publish Date: <BO:publisher_date>2001</BO:publisher_date></p>
        <p>Genre: <BO:genre>Poetry</BO:genre></p>
        <p>Subject: <BO:subject>Human Mind</BO:subject></p>
        <p>Category: <BO:category>Self-Help</BO:category></p>
        <p>File Size: <BO:file_size>122 MB</BO:file_size></p>
        <p>Pages: <BO:pages>3</BO:pages></p>
        <p>Price: <span id="dollar">$</span><BO:price>142.99</BO:price></p>
        <p>Payment Method: <BO:payment_method>Paypal</BO:payment_method></p>
    </BO:book>  

</BO:books_for_sale>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Not sure where this has gone wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DTD is fine but you can't check it directly with `xmllint`; you have to check an XML file.

Your other file is a problem. You should split out the XML, and since you are using a DTD, don't use a namespace. (You could rewrite the DTD, treating namespace declarations as an attribute and the prefixed elements as complete names but in XML a namespace declaration is not an attribute and can appear on any element, and prefixes are arbitrary. So, the concepts don't translate well.)

The other thing wrong is that an HTML render will ignore any non-standard tags so that takes out the whole body of the document. When you transfer data from XML to HTML (even XHTML), be sure to put the data you want rendered in HTML tags. You can do this with XSLT.

XML file...

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE books_for_sale SYSTEM "book.dtd">
<books_for_sale>
    <book>
        <book_id>BK12345</book_id>
        <title>Gray Geese Crying</title>
        <author>Bill Nedham</author>
        <co_author_name>Surely Joking</co_author_name>
        <editor_name>Fried Brian</editor_name>
        <illustrator_name>Drew Sumthin</illustrator_name>
        <language>Orangatang</language>
        <ISBN>9912385748391</ISBN>
        <publisher>Random Random Homes</publisher>
        <publisher_date>2001</publisher_date>
        <genre>Poetry</genre>
        <subject>Human Mind</subject>
        <category>Self-Help</category>
        <file_size>122 MB</file_size>
        <pages>3</pages>
        <price>142.99</price>
        <payment_method>Paypal</payment_method>
    </book>  
</books_for_sale>
```

So, when you want to produce the HTML use a stylesheet like this:
XSLT file...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head>
<title>Book Order</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="book.css"></link>
</head>
<body>

<div class="page-wrap">

<h3>Books for Sale</h3>
<h4>Great Prices! Limted Selection! No Delivery!</h4>

<!-- present books for sale -->
      <xsl:for-each select="books_for_sale/book">
        <div>
            <p>Book ID: <xsl:value-of select="book_id" /></p>
            <p>Price: <span id="dollar">$<xsl:value-of select="price" /></span></p>
            <p>Payment Method: <xsl:value-of select="payment_method" /></p>
        </div>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for getting me on the right track Tom. I appreciate your effort. I'll post my success or failure when I finish up my code modifications this afternoon.

Comment: Tom. The suggested code you wrote got me right on track. I'm not sure how I got the HTML and XML combined file I initially posted. But I'm understanding what my errors were and appreciate your assistance. Thank you so very much.